# I can't insert the supplier_id even it is already associated the two model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-resources

I have a form then I tried to insert in the supplier profile model which are  company name, address and description also this model associatd in the supplier model. There is no error but when I view the database the supplier id part has no data.

Supplierprofile model

```
belongs_to :supplier
```

Supplier model

```
has_one   :supplierprofile
```

routes.rb

```
resources :supplierprofiles
  resources :supplierunits

  resources :suppliers do
    resources :supplierprofiles
    resources :supplierunits
  end

resources :sessions, except: :show do
    member do 
      delete 'logout'
      get    'home'
      get    'profile'
      get    'setting'
    end
  end
```

SupplierProfile Controller

```
    before_action :set_supplierprofile, only: [:new, :create, :show]

    def new
        @profile = @supplier.build_supplierprofile
    end

    def create

        if @profile = @supplier.create_supplierprofile(profile_params)

            respond_to do |format|
                format.html { redirect_to home_session_url(session[:user_id]),
                              notice: "Profile Completed!" }
            end
        else
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
            end
        end
    end

    private

    def set_supplierprofile
        @supplier = Supplier.find(session[:user_id])
    end

    def profile_params
        params.require(:supplierprofile).permit(:company_name, :address, :description)
    end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for([@supplier, @profile]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input       :company_name %>
  <%= f.input       :address      %>
  <%= f.text_area   :description  %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your code looks ok to me.  Do you get the same behaviour if you do something like `Profile.first.create_supplierprofile(company_name: 'x')` in the rails console?

Comment: I try this in the console sir.. supplier = Supplier.find(2)then '
profile = supplier.create_supplierprofile(company_name: "Voicesee", address: "CDO", description: "App")' .... It works, the supplier_id was store.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.. The codes will to much long if I paste here. but I can discuss here the solution flow, when I try to redirect_to home_session_url(session[:user_id]) I forgot that there was a callback function that check_profile and it will create an instance supplierprofile then in the console there was an update query. So, the solution I created was redirect to different method called dashboard then boom. I'm just new to rails. Thank you!

Comment: glad you figured it out!